# Unit testing with Generic repository, UnitOfWork, NUnit and Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit, moq, unit-of-work

There are lots of articles with a topic similar to this on StackOverflow, but I have not found any articles dedicated precisely to my situation.

I am trying to make unit tests with Moq and NUnit for Generic repository with Unit of Work pattern implemented.

Here is a code of the generic repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TContext, TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class 
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly TContext Context;

    public GenericRepository(TContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> CreateRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        if (entities == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return entities;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Retrieve(object entityId)
    {
        return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(entityId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Retrieve(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(entity);
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> UpdateRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        var updateRange = entities as TEntity[] ?? entities.ToArray();
        if (updateRange.Any(entity => entity == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        foreach (var entity in updateRange)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Context.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(entity);
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return updateRange;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> SafeDelete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var propertySet = TrySetProperty(entity, "Is_deleted", true);
        if (!propertySet)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(entity);
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> SafeDeleteRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        var safeDeleteRange = entities as TEntity[] ?? entities.ToArray();
        if (safeDeleteRange.Any(entity => entity == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var propertySet = false;
        foreach (var entity in safeDeleteRange)
        {
            propertySet = TrySetProperty(entity, "Is_deleted", true);
        }
        if (!propertySet)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        foreach (var entity in safeDeleteRange)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Context.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(entity);
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return safeDeleteRange;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity));
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> DeleteRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        if (entities == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities));
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return entities;
    }

    private static bool TrySetProperty(object obj, string property, object value)
    {
        var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (prop == null || !prop.CanWrite)
        {
            return false;
        }
        prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a unit test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class GenericRepositoryUnitTests
{
    private Mock<IDomainRepository> _repo;
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWork;
    private Mock<IUnitOfWorkFactory<DmsDbContext>> _unitOfWorkFactory;
    private Mock<DmsDbContext> _mockContext;
    private Mock<DbSet<Domain>> _mockSet;
    private List<Domain> _domains;
    private User _user;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var userId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _user = new User
        {
            UsersId = userId,
            Username = "Test",
            Password = "Test",
            First_name = "Test",
            Last_name = "Test",
            Img = "Test",
            Permissions = "Test",
            Is_deleted = false
        };
        _domains = new List<Domain>
        {
            new Domain
            {
                DomainId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Test",
                Url = "Test",
                Is_deleted = false,
                Users = new List<User>
                {
                    _user,
                    new User
                    {
                        UsersId = userId,
                        Username = "Test",
                        Password = "Test",
                        First_name = "Test",
                        Last_name = "Test",
                        Img = "Test",
                        Permissions = "Test",
                        Is_deleted = false
                    },
                    new User
                    {
                        UsersId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Username = "Test",
                        Password = "Test",
                        First_name = "Test",
                        Last_name = "Test",
                        Img = "Test",
                        Permissions = "Test",
                        Is_deleted = false
                    }
                }
            },
            new Domain
            {
                DomainId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Test",
                Url = "Test",
                Is_deleted = false,
                Users = new List<User>
                {
                    _user,
                    new User
                    {
                        UsersId = userId,
                        Username = "Test",
                        Password = "Test",
                        First_name = "Test",
                        Last_name = "Test",
                        Img = "Test",
                        Permissions = "Test",
                        Is_deleted = false
                    },
                    new User
                    {
                        UsersId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Username = "Test",
                        Password = "Test",
                        First_name = "Test",
                        Last_name = "Test",
                        Img = "Test",
                        Permissions = "Test",
                        Is_deleted = false
                    }
                }
            },
            new Domain
            {
                DomainId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Test",
                Url = "Test",
                Is_deleted = false,
                Users = new List<User>
                {
                    _user,
                    new User
                    {
                        UsersId = userId,
                        Username = "Test",
                        Password = "Test",
                        First_name = "Test",
                        Last_name = "Test",
                        Img = "Test",
                        Permissions = "Test",
                        Is_deleted = false
                    },
                    new User
                    {
                        UsersId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Username = "Test",
                        Password = "Test",
                        First_name = "Test",
                        Last_name = "Test",
                        Img = "Test",
                        Permissions = "Test",
                        Is_deleted = false
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        
        _mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Domain>>();
        _mockSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Domain>())).Returns(new Domain());

        _mockContext = new Mock<DmsDbContext>();
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Domain>()).Returns(_mockSet.Object);

        _repo = new Mock<IDomainRepository>{CallBase = true};
        _repo.Setup(r => r.Context).Returns(_mockContext.Object);
        _repo.Setup(r => r.Create(It.IsAny<Domain>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(new Domain()));
        _repo.Setup(r => r.CreateRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Domain>>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new List<Domain>().AsEnumerable()));
        _repo.Setup(r => r.Retrieve(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(_domains.AsEnumerable().First()));
        _repo.Setup(r => r.Retrieve(pre => pre.Is_deleted == false))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(_domains.AsEnumerable()));
        _repo.Setup(r => r.Update(It.IsAny<Domain>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(new Domain()));
        _repo.Setup(r => r.Delete(It.IsAny<Domain>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(new Domain()));
        _repo.Setup(r => r.DeleteRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Domain>>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new List<Domain>().AsEnumerable()));

        _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.Domains).Returns(_repo.Object);

        _unitOfWorkFactory = new Mock<IUnitOfWorkFactory<DmsDbContext>>();
        _unitOfWorkFactory.Setup(u => u.Create(It.IsAny<DmsDbContext>())).Returns(_unitOfWork.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Create_NewDomainObject_AddToDatabase()
    {
        // Arrange
        var domain = new Domain
        {
            DomainId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Test",
            Url = "Test",
            Is_deleted = false,
            Users = new List<User> { _user }
        };

        // Act
        using var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Object.Create(_mockContext.Object);
        await unitOfWork.Domains.Create(domain);

        // Assert
        _repo.Verify(m => m.Context.Set<Domain>().Add(It.IsAny<Domain>()), Times.Once());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Retrieve_TestDomainObjectById_ReturnsValue()
    {
        //Arrange
        var domainId = Guid.NewGuid();

        using var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Object.Create(_mockContext.Object);
        // Act
        var domain = unitOfWork.Domains.Retrieve(domainId);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(domain);
    }
```

I cannot make these tests working and have no idea, what is wrong.

Could someone please explain me, how to properly test the generic repository with a set of tools mentioned above?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're essentially not testing anything at all. All you're doing is creating mock objects and testing against them to see if they work the same way as your concrete implementation (which will never work). You need to test a repository that implements your Generic Repository, and use moq to mock your dependencies.

Comment: Hey @Hayden, thanks for quick explanation! Topic of unit testing is quite new for me, so could you please provide some example of proper unit testing of generic repository? I have found a lot of them, but they are related to testing Retrieve method only. Rest of them is a mystery for me so far :D If you could provide an exact implementation of unit test for Create method, for instance, it would be really nice and moreover will give me a clear understanding of what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Hayden's comment: You are testing the wrong thing. Using a repository pattern (Though I recommend steering *away* from the Generic Repository pattern) is about isolating business logic from it's dependency on domain, so that you can unit test the business logic in isolation.

As a simple example: If I have a controller or service that has a method that performs an update that retrieves an set of entities from the domain, performs some validation, applies some changes, and saves those entities:

If I use the DbContext directly:

```
public void SomeAction(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var someEntity = context.Entities.Include(x=> x.Children).Include(x=> x.Category).Single(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id);

        if(!x.Category.IsLocked)
        {
            // copy values from view model to entity...

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is to test SomeAction I can define a ViewModel, but having it instantiate a DbContext means I have a hard dependency on a data source that will behave in a predictable way for that test. I may want tests to cover behaviour when: An entity isn't found, an entity has a locked category, an entity has an unlocked category, etc.

So we introduce the Repository pattern to abstract the repository and encompassing Unit of Work. The method changes more towards something like:

```
public void SomeAction(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
    {
        var someEntity = ActionRepository.GetEntityById(viewModel.Id)
            .Include(x=> x.Children).Include(x=> x.Category)
            .Single();

        if(!x.Category.IsLocked)
        {
            // copy values from view model to entity...

            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

UnitOfWorkFactory and ActionRepository are injected dependencies of my controller. ActionRepository exposes the methods I need to interact with the domain. In my example I use methods that return `IQueryable<TEntity>` as it accommodates very thin abstractions to substitute.  I don't Test what the repository or unit of work do, I mock the unit of work and repository so that I can write tests to assert what my controller action does. My test mocks can simulate returning No matching entity, or an entity with a locked category, or a perfectly valid entity for specific test scenarios. They can go so far as to assert whether SaveChanges on the unit of work should, and does get called. Though it can be argued that this is diving into testing the specific implementation of your method which can make your tests more brittle. Ultimately you aim to write tests for specific outputs for specific scenarios where the mocks enable you to easily set up those scenarios.